# How to mock a service in a test file that is being called in OnInit of the component being tested?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

In AutoReceptionistRecommendation.component.ts

I have an ngOninit method that looks like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.city = this.employee.getEmpData().city;
  }
```

In the test file AutoReceptionistRecommendation.component.spec.ts

I have code that looks like this:

```
describe('AutoReceptionistRecommendationComponent', () => {
  let component: AutoReceptionistRecommendationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AutoReceptionistRecommendationComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AutoReceptionistRecommendationComponent ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatIconModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      providers: [
        EmployeeService,
        EmployeeHttpService
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AutoReceptionistRecommendationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

When I run ng test I get an error that looks like this:

> Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':
>   Failed to load
>   'ng:///DynamicTestModule/AutoReceptionistRecommendationComponent_Host.ngfactory.js'.

If I remove the line in NgOnInit this error does not occur, and the test continues. I think that I have to mock this service somehow in order for the test to go through. What is the best way to do that, can somebody provide documentation that explains how to do this? Or give me insight as to why this error occurs with the line in ngOninit and does not occur when it is not there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficient unit testing requires to isolate currently tested unit from other moving parts.

Real `HttpModule` shouldn't be used in unit tests. The requests should be mocked with `MockBackend` when testing the units that use `Http` *directly*. Otherwise these units should be mocked, like:

```
providers: [
  ...
  { provide: EmployeeService, useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('', ['getEmpData']) }
]
```

Component `ngOnInit` is called on first `detectChanges` call. This means that `employee.getEmpData` should be mocked beforehand:

```
component = fixture.componentInstance;
employee.getEmpData.and.returnValue({ city: ... });
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks that seems like a good idea and the right way to go. Butas of now the way employee is written causes a compile error. How do you create an instance of EmployeeService?

Comment: You inject it with inject(...) or TestBed.get, like any other service in tests.

Comment: Thanks, while I am new to angular testing so am probably lacking knowledge, which is why I had a difficult time getting it to work... I found most of your answer helpful, but I also found this blog helpful http://www.kirjai.com/testing-angular-services-with-dependencies/ ... What I decided to do instead, was create a MockStub for the Service class that I wanted to mock. And used that which seemed to solve the problem. If you think that is bad and wrong, let me know.

Comment: You're welcome. Jasmine spies are superior to custom mock classes. Just because Jasmine spies can be *spied* and change their behaviour on the fly with `.and...`. You may want to make sure that `getEmpData` was called in ngOnInit. You'll have to reinvent the wheel if you don't use them.